PMD Salesforce Code Analyzer error "invalid type" for custom object
I'm trying to comply with Salesforce Code Analyzer, but I found a strange error with an Apex class.
The class was designed to be called from an Apex trigger (originally, the trigger had the logic, but now it simply calls to the class).
Since the class does DML operations, I'm trying to avoid those operations within loops.
Here is the class:
public without sharing class BC_ClaseCierraAtencion {
    public static void cierra(List<BC_Atenci_n__c> atenciones){
        // do stuff...        
    }
}


Note the class does the job (there's no error in the operation.)
The Code Analyzer shows an error in the List<BC_Atenci_n__c> atenciones parameter/argument. The analyzer doesn't recognize a custom object. The error message is "Invalid type: BC_Atenci_n__c" (where BC_Atenci_n__c is a custom object).
What can it be?
Thx
Trying to comply with PMD Code Analyzer I found that it doesn't recognize a custom object's name (BC_Atenci_n__c) anywhere in the code.

Which version of PMD are you using? This looks like a parsing error. The language parser changed completely from PMD 6 to PMD 7, make sure to be using an up to date version.

Finally, with the help of eyescream and some research, I could fix it by refreshing the sObject definitions
Shift + Command + P refresh sobject definitions
And I got what I needed.
Thanks!

I don't recognise such error message, it's not on the standard list: https://pmd.github.io/pmd/pmd_rules_apex.html.
Which tool exactly are you using, the sf/sfdx commandline plugin? The VSCode plugin? Something else like "raw" PMD with Apex-specific ruleset passed to it? PMD bundled with CI solution (Gearset, Clayton...)?
I suspect your predecessor/lead developer/architect added a custom rule to standard checks and it's that rule that's throwing the errors. Find out how you're running PMD and whether there's a file passed to it with structure similar to https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-apex/src/main/resources/rulesets/apex/quickstart.xml
You'll have to check "what was the author thinking". Maybe your company has coding standards that say sObjects should be BcAtenciN__c?

I am using VS Code (MacOS), installed the extension and run the scan. Here is another example: In this line: "ContentVersion cVersion = new ContentVersion();" there is an error "Invalid type: ContentVersion [Ln 21, Col 9]" (severity 4).

Note "BC_Atenci_n__c" is a custom object we created in the Salesforce org, and need to access within the Apex class...

Check your extension's settings? What's in apexPMD.rulesets? I suspect it'll be path to xml file with rules somebody in the past specified for your project. The file is likely committed to Git, maybe even in repository's top folder

Published
2023-09-06, 17:57:33
Last released
2024-06-25, 13:05:51
Last updated
2024-07-09, 15:08:04
Identifier
salesforce.sfdx-code-analyzer-vscode

No. VSCode settings, under the cog/gear icon in bottom left or Ctrl+, (Command+, on Mac I think). Type "rulesets" into the search box. Does it show something (I believe you'll have there a custom ruleset) or empty, meaning you use standard one

Apologies for the delay in answering. I have reviewed these settings: "Apex PMD: Rulesets" and it's empty. There's an "(Optional) Paths to rulesets' xml files" message, and a button "Add item". That's it...

If it's not a custom rule, the error msg doesn't contain link to explanation, the parser is recent... Out of ideas

I just discovered that the folder /.sfdx/tools/sobjects doesn't contain any classes (.cls files) with the custom objects I have built, and I don't know how to retrieve these "cls". I guess that's why the analyzer can't find the data types.

Don't think that's it, PMD tends to work on 1 file, not "look around". But do press Ctrl+Shift+P (or whatever is Mac equivalent, Command+Shift+P?) "refresh sobject definitions"?

It did the trick. Thank you very much
